# Encryption Registration is obsolete as o September 20, 2016; means no annual email reports?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

My iOS App uses Fabric, Google Maps + do HTTPS requests to external servers. Encryption Registration is obsolete as o September 20, 2016, but according to https://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/policy-guidance/encryption/15-policy-guidance/encryption/261-reporting, I'm still obligated to send annual reports to crypt-supp8@bis.doc.gov and enc@nsa.gov with subject "Self-classification report for ERN R######". I'm new in AppStore, it's my first iOS app so my company has no ERN number.

Questions:

1. Does www.bis.doc.gov contain obsolete information? No Encryption Registration means no annual reports?
2. www.bis.doc.gov contains valid information, so what subject pattern should I use?

I really spend lot of time on this, because I want to fulfill all legal requirements, but my but I speak code, not lawyer, so I still can't clarify this last part. Appreciate for help.

Comment: What has this to do with Xamarin at all?

Comment: it's related to itunesconnect only, just removed xamarin tag

Comment: did you hear back from them after sending the email ?? and what did you put for ERN ### ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the response I received from AppStore:

> Yes,  www.bis.doc.gov contains obsolete information.  If one reviews the actual regulation it states: 
>   (A) Submissions via e-mail. Submit your encryption self-classification report electronically to BIS at crypt-supp8@bis.doc.gov and to the ENC Encryption Request Coordinator at enc@nsa.gov, as an attachment to an e-mail.
>
> Identify your e-mail with subject “self-classification report.”
>
> Regards,
>
> Apple Export Compliance
>   appstore.ec@apple.com